# How to handle map in response if not data?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I have method that executes request to server:

```
public get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(URL + "get").pipe(
      map((result) => {
        result["data"].forEach((item) => {
          item.title = "title";
        });

        return result["data"];
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(error))
    );
  }
```

But it failed on line `result["data"]` because response returns nothing.

How to fix it?

Comment: Post the returned `json`. You can get this from the debugging tools in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing a simple `if` check:

```
public get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(URL + "get").pipe(
      map((result) => {
        if (result['data']) {
          result["data"].forEach((item) => {
            item.title = "title";
          });
        }
        // this may return undefined.
        return result["data"];
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(error))
    );
  }
```

If you want to filter responses, check out the `filter` operator of `rjxs`. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can consider using the [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) operator, which will complete the observable only if `result.data` is defined. This is how you can implement it:

```
public get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(URL + "get").pipe(
      filter((result) => result['data']),
      map((result) => {
        result["data"].forEach((item) => {
          item.title = "title";
        });

        return result["data"];
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(error))
    );
  }
```